# Service area shortest time/distance to cover all lines - network analysis

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, network-analysis

I have a network of roads that all have to be covered by car. So I'm not looking for the fastest way from point to point, but the fastest (or shortest) way to run my vehicle along ALL the roads within the red dotted border. The start point could be set at any point within the polygon, as long as the total distance/time is as low as possible. Any ideas on how to adress that issue in QGIS 3.30.1?

[image]

Comment: This is commonly known as the ["Chinese Postman Problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_postman_problem). I don't have a QGIS solution right now, but perhaps knowing what to search for will help you along the way.

Comment: What you can always do in QGIS when you know the name of the problem: look at Menu Processing > Toolbox > enter the name to see if there is a tool for it. Nothing found for Chinese Postman Problem. The second step is to look if there is a plugin. And there is one: Chinese Postman Solver: https://github.com/rkistner/chinese-postman

Comment: Thanks for the info Matt.

@Babel yeah that's what I did. However I cannot get the tool running since I always get an error for the Python code that comes with the plugin